# How to use facets on jupyter without having the whole directory structure?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, facet

I want to use facets for visualizing pandas dataframes. I am able to do it within the directory structure of facets with a clone of the github repo (https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets).

Is it possible to use facets outside of this kind of like matplotlib, plotly, or seaborn?